# Does there exist a CLI spaced repetition program?

Tags: software-recommendation, education

I'm aware of anki and mnemosyne, but not of any way to get them to run in a terminal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://github.com/darius/spaced-out

https://github.com/theq629/fulgurate

https://github.com/itsdawomb/ebblite

There also used to be yellowcot, memonerd, and ankitty for anki (not sure they still exist)

Best wishes, J

Comment: I started my own on github, but it looks like you found better answers!